# split string based on delimiter javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a string by a delimiter so that it becomes 2 arrays.
Here is an example of string `"55,56,*,51,52"`.

I want to end up with `[["55","56],["51","52"]]`
I have trie with split() in javascript to no avail-
I believe I need a regex solution, which I do not know how to do.

if the string to process looks like this `",*,51,52"` it should return
`[[],["51,"52"]]`
if it looks like  `"51,*,"` it should return `[["51"],[]]`
and `",*,"` should return `[[],[]]` -

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version without using split:

```
function twoArrays(str) {
  return JSON.parse(("[[" + str + "]]").replace(/,\*,/g, "],["));
}

// Examples:
twoArrays("55,56,*,51,52") // => [[55,56],[51,52]]
twoArrays("55,56,*,")      // => [[55,56],[]]
twoArrays(",*,")           // => [[],[]]
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token * . Am I  not designating the delimiter correctly?

Comment: This worked great and is shorter than the first answer, which also worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via the `string.split` method:

```
var str = "55,56,*,51,52".split('*');
for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) str[i] = str[i].split(',');
//str now contains [["55", "56", ""], ["", "51", "52"]]
```

You can change your string to `"55,56*51,52"` to get the result of `[["55","56],["51","52"]]`.

Alternatively, you can also do it the slightly longer way:

```
var str = "55,56,*,51,52".split('*');
for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].split(',');
    for (var n=0;n<str[i].length;n++)
        !str[i][n] && str[i].splice(n,1);
}
//str now contains [["55","56],["51","52"]]
```

Then it will work with the commas around the asterisk.

Comment: you could also just use regex to look for a `,` either at start or end of string and remove it.

Comment: If the split method will take a regex, those comma's could be stripped in the first split with `,?\*,?`

Comment: Or a non-regex `,*,` if the OP is sure it is always that form.